# Удаление файлов во всех папках пользователей

Tags: c#, файловая-система

Есть программа которая удаляет файлы в папках пользователя, но только в конкретной папке к которой я указываю путь, как сделать что бы это удаление происходило во всех папках пользователей которые есть на компе ?

```
        string path = @"D:\AppFolders\";
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
        foreach (string dir in dirs)
        {
            int delDay = 200;
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
                if (fi.LastWriteTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-delDay))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        fi.Delete();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) { }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: перебрать всех пользователей не пытались?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду перебрать через for ?

Comment: хоть через for, хоть через foreach

Comment: @Monomax добавил код который у меня получился, перебираю циклом, по папкам переходит, но он не проходит папки дальше что бы удалять файлы, что написал не так?

Comment: временно уберите обертку  try...catch и посмотрите на что жалуется. А лучше выведите в блоке `catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.message);Console.Read() }`

Answer (score 3):

Зачем вам это надо? Если ваша программа использует некие общие кэши, системные настройки и т.п., то имеет смысл хранить данные в общей директории `ProgramData`, например.

Я так понимаю, вы получаете директорию, в которой производите файловые операции, с помощью `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.*)`? С технической стороны есть несколько вариантов:

1. Архитектурно верный способ — это имперсонифицироваться с помощью [`LogonUser`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonusera), а затем получить директорию с помощью [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath), передав полученный токен. Для этого вам нужны будут имена и пароли пользователей.
2. Если хочется грязно и быстро, то можно залезть в реестр и прочитать недокументированные ключи:

   - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` для получения SIDов.
   - `HKEY_USERS\{SID}\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders` для получения директорий.

   Если в новой версии системы ключи будут отсутствовать, ваша программа перестанет работать.
3. Если хочется ещё грязнее и быстрее, то с помощью `Environment.GetFolderPath` получите директорию `Users`, получите имя директории, которая вам нужна, а потом пройдитесь по всем папкам в поисках похожих. Если пользователь менял положение директорий, то будет сюрприз: или ничего не удалится, или удалится не то, что нужно.
4. Если хочется скрипт на один раз, чтобы написать и запустить один раз и больше не вспоминать, можно даже пропустить чтение имён с помощью `Environment.GetFolderPath` и сразу лезть в папку `Users`. А этом случае ваша программа перестанет работать даже банально на системе на другом языке.

Comment: можете подробнее описать этот способ пожалуйста? Директорию Юзерс я получил, а как дальше быть с той которая мне нужна?

Comment: @JoshuaHiggs Какой "этот"? Для начала опишите, что именно и зачем вы делаете.